# Simply connected cover of $SO(2,\mathbb{R})$

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, covering-spaces

If $G$ is a Lie group with algebra $\frak g$ which is not simply connected and has fundamental group $\pi_1(G)$, then there exists a larger Lie group $G_0$, the cover of $G$, which has the same algebra and is simply connected. Moreover, $G\sim G_0/\pi_1(G)$.

I want to apply this theory to $SO(2,\mathbb{R})$. What is the cover of $SO(2,\mathbb{R})$?

1) I know of the relation $S^1\sim \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$. Is this the answer? Notice that here the group $\mathbb{R}$ is defined with + as its operation.

2) On the other hand, the Lie algebra of $SO(2,\mathbb{R})$ is the real line. Exponential of the real line, $e^{x}$, produces the group $\mathbb{R}_+$, positive reals with $\times$ as operation. Is this the answer?

I am confused.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, the answer is $(\mathbb{R},+)$. The covering map from $\mathbb R$ onto $SO(2,\mathbb{R})$ is simply $t\mapsto\left(\begin{smallmatrix}\cos t&-\sin t\\\sin t&\cos t\end{smallmatrix}\right)$.

Concerning the exponential map, don't attach too much meaning to the this name. If you see $\mathbb R$ as the Lie algebra of the Lie group $(\mathbb{R},+)$, then the exponential map is just the identity (yes, you read it right). And if you see $\mathbb R$ as the Lie algebra of the Lie group $SO(2,\mathbb{R})$, then the exponential map is the map that I defined in my previous paragraph.

Comment: But I expected the cover to have the same product operation as the quotient. Is this expectation misguided?

Comment: Also, what is wrong with line 2) of reasoning?

Comment: @thedude Totally so. What do you mean by “the same operation”? We have two different *sets* here, none of which is a subset of the other one. There is now way that it could be the same operation.

Comment: @thedude I shall edit my answer in order to reply to your other comment.

Comment: It might be useful to mention that $\begin{pmatrix}\cos t&-\sin t\\\sin t&\cos t\end{pmatrix}$ is an exponential (in the usual sense for matrices), namely $\exp\begin{pmatrix}0&-t\\t&0\end{pmatrix}$.